# J2ME App Install by Network

Tags: mobile, java-me, sms, j2mepolish

I develop on J2ME test App, I can install in my old nokia using Bluetooth, IR, Cable.

But there is any way of sending this App using SMS or other network based protocol?

Comment: did you consider [MIDP OTA provisioning](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/ota/)? **...ability to download and install content over a wireless network...**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you can do via SMS is to send a URL to your MIDlet's .jad file.

Answer (score 1):

You can put your jad and jar in the internet. Create a wap (or web) page that can be accessed by the device. In the wml (html) file, there must be a link that points to your jad file like this:

```
<a href="app_location/MyJMEApp.jad">This is my JME App!</a>
```

Normally, you put the jad and jar file in one folder and so you have this in the jad file:

```
MIDlet-Jar-URL: MyJMEApp.jar
```

But if not, then you have to indicate it in the value of MIDlet-Jar-URL. If you open the wap (web) page on your device and click on the link, the device will download and install the MyJMEApp.jar.